# How to evaluate formula cell when using event way to read a xlsx file use ApachePOI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Due to memory consideration, I use the UserEventModel to read an xlsx file. As we known, there will be cached result in the XML file. However, in some cases(like using google sheet), the numeric cell value is not precise and some digits are truncated.
So we have the requirement to re-evaluate the formula cell. However, it seems that only UserModel currently can evaluate the formula cell.
And I can not find an easy solution to evaluate the formula cell in UserEventModel. It will be appreciated if you can provide some information.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your two options are either to buy some more memory, or to script opening and saving again with a real copy of Excel...

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, why it is difficult to deal with formula evaluation when using UserEventModel. Will this feature be taken in POI's plan?

Comment: Formulas normally refer to other cells. If you only have the one cell right now, have thrown away previous cells, and haven't yet read future cells, how on earth is it supposed to know what values to use? The only option is to keep everything in memory, which is what the normal usermodel stuff does!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gagravarr. I know it.

Comment: @Gagravarr I also have a question. What is the difference when I call POIFSFileSystem(java.io.File file) and POIFSFileSystem(java.io.InputStream stream), since I met Heapsize OOM in the InputStream calling.

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream for details